# Can you use a class inside the member function of that class c++

Tags: c++, class, object

Is it possible to define a member function for a class that is the type of class you are defining.

```
class aClass {
//Some Stuff
aClass aFunction(. . .);
};
```

Comment: You could put this into an IDE and try to compile it.

Comment: How hard to try it yourself? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c85c40cb5744bb00

Comment: Of course it's possible, and it's done all the time. What made you suspect otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, and it's very handy.

> Overloading:

```
class vec2
{
    float x;
    float y;

    vec2 operator+(vec2 otherVector) 
    {    
         vec2 returnVector;
         returnVector.x = this.x + otherVector.x;
         returnVector.y = this.y + otherVector.y;
         return returnVector;
    }

}
```

Which allows you to do stuff like this:

```
vec2 myVector = thatVector + theOtherVector;
```

Because it sets myVector to the return value of `thatVector + theOtherVector` which is now a vector containing the sum of the other vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return an instance of a class from a member function of that class.